# jQuery Datatables bSearchable filter on input values

Tags: jquery, datatables

Alright so I have a pretty standard dynamic datatable but I cannot seem to get the search box to filter based on the value of an input or select box.

```
oTable = $('#itemTable').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "sDom": '<""f>t<"F"lp>',
            "aoColumns": [
                { "sWidth": "45px", "bSearchable": false},
                { "sWidth": "150px"}, // <input type="text">
                { "sWidth": "150px"}, // <select>
                { "sWidth": "150px"}, // <select>
                { "sWidth": "125px"}, // <input type="text">
                { "sWidth": "75px", "bSearchable": false},
                { "sWidth": "75px", "bSearchable": false},
                { "sWidth": "75px", "bSearchable": false},
                { "sWidth": "75px", "bSearchable": false},
                { "sWidth": "75px", "bSearchable": false}
            ],
```

How can I get the datatable to filter the search results based on the value of a text box, and/or the current selected value of a select box?

I found this [jQuery DataTables - custom filter for column that contains text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043458/jquery-datatables-custom-filter-for-column-that-contains-text-field) but I cant seem to make that work for me

Comment: I just realized i need to be using mDataProp....this question is on hold as I work through this...

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this to work using the [jquery-datatables-column-filter plugin](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-column-filter/) for jquery datatables

once you include that you can just add `.columnFilter()` to your datatable. The great part about this plugin is you can use the data tables "aoColumns" as normal and the `.columnFilter()` just overwrites that particular columns,  I just included other datatable settings to show this, see example below:

```
var asInitVals = new Array();

$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable( {
        "bPaginate": true,
        "fnDrawCallback":function(){$('.edit').editable(function(value, settings) { 
                            hasBeenEdited(this);
                            return(value);
                         }, { 
                            type    : 'text',
                            submit  : 'OK'
                        });},

        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Search all columns:",
        },
        "aoColumns": [
                        { "bSortable": true ,"bSearchable": true},
                        { "bSearchable": true},
                        {"bSortable": true ,  "bSearchable" : true}, 
                        {"bSearchable": true }, 
                        {"bSearchable": true }, 
                        { },
                        { }
                    ]
    } ).columnFilter({"aoColumns":[{ type: "select", values: [ 'Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3']  },
         null,
         null,
         null,
         null,
         null,
         null]});
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mRender attribute in the aoColumns to specify the selected value of the select box for filtering

```
"mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
    if (type === "filter")
    {
          node = $.parseHTML(data);
          var val = $(node).find("select option:selected").text();                     
              return val;
    }
    return data;
}
```